# How can we set up MariaDB to create a new queries.log file each day?

Tags: mysql, logging, mariadb, centos7

On our Centos 7 server, we discovered recently that the MariaDB queries.log file (/var/log/mariadb/queries.log) was massive (over 4GB in size). This single large file isn't a practical solution for periodic log reviews.

Ideally, I'd like to have a new log get created every day. It would look something like this:

queries.log
queries-3132018.log
queries-3122018.log
queries-3112018.log

Does anyone know how we could implement this sort of logging feature with MariaDB?

Comment: Read this blog: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/18/rotating-mysql-slow-logs-safely/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you won't be able to get this result only from your MariaDB server settings.

Depending on what kind of queries you are interested in, you may have a look at the binary log feature instead. This will only log every query that modifies your data and your data structure (ie inserts, updates, alters, etc.). With binary logs, you can specify a max size to reach before the server creates a new file (max_binlog_size variable). You can also set up a delay before your older logs will be purged (expire_logs_days variable).
(See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/ for more information)

If these binary logs features don't suit your needs, then I'm afraid you'll have to make a script to rotate your queries log, and schedule it to run periodically.

Comment: I think you may be right. Bill Karwin's link suggests something similar, essentially running a script that mv's the current log file to a newly renamed file, and then creating a new log file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [MariaDB Audit plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin/).

The plugin has the in-built log rotation mechanism, where you can configure the size of the log (`server_audit_file_rotate_size`) and the number of rotations to save (`server_audit_file_rotations`).

By adjusting the value of `server_audit_events`, it can be configured to log various events. If you only want to log queries, it is also possible, it would look somewhat like that:

```
20180314 01:32:22,ws,root,::1,23,8399,QUERY,test,'create table t2 (i int)',0
20180314 01:32:26,ws,root,::1,23,8400,QUERY,test,'insert into t2 values (1)',0
20180314 01:32:29,ws,root,::1,23,8401,QUERY,test,'select * from t2',0
```

The plugin comes as `server_audit.so` library and needs to be installed in the usual fashion, via `INSTALL SONAME` or `INSTALL PLUGIN` or `--plugin-load-add`.